# json parsing error because of datas in different lines

Tags: android

Now I am doing an Android application. Now I am facing a problem in json parsing.My json page structure is like this.

```
[
{

"id":3,

"name":"dd"

},

{

"id":4,

"name":"ggg"

}

]
```

I tried with the following code.

```
URL website = new URL("url");
InputStream in = website.openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
JSONArray ary=new JSONArray(line);
}
```

but I am getting exception.Because all the datas are in different lines.if it in the same line 
[{"id":3,"name":"dd"},{"id":4,"name":"ggg"}] then i can do easily...but they provide all datas in separate line ..thats the problem..Pls help me friends

Comment: `dd` and `ggg` should be quoted, otherwise it is an invalid `JSON`.

Comment: I don't see that in your example. Also, trying to parse JSON line-by-line won't lead you to success.

Comment: then giv me a simple example to read data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I got..

```
    public void parseMovie(InputStream json) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        JSONArray jsonReply = new JSONArray(sb.toString()); 

        System.out.println("length is"+jsonReply.length());
        ArrayList<String> id=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonReply.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonMovie = jsonReply.getJSONObject(0); 


            id.add(jsonMovie.getString("id"));

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the whole data, only then parse it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
JSONArray ary=new JSONArray(sb.toString());
```

Comment: java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: it means that you have a problem with the connection, you didn't get to the JSON part yet...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("url");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v("in else", "Failed to download file");
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.v("Builder >>", builder.toString());
    String response=builder.toString();
```